# Click on dropdown items with Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How should I click on an item in this drop-down menu with Selenium + Python?

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
      <select name="per_page" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
         <!-- <option value="5" >5</option> -->
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="20">25</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
         <option value="100" selected="selected">100</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
select_obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control'))
select_obj.select_by_visible_text('100')
```

I get this error:

```
Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Is there any other input field in the HTML with the class name 'form-control'?

Comment: DEBUG this -- driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control') #find elementS.
Get len of the result to check how many matches

Comment: @Wonka I got 32.

Comment: That means this element appears 32 times. Please find the unique path for this select element. You can use xpath.The class_name: 'form-control' is not unique in the HTML. You can use this xpath: "//select[@name='per_page']"

Comment: Thats the problem, wihtout 's' it get the first item, as @Monika said, find a specific XPath, post url or complete HTML. Probably this help you (didnt test) :=> select_obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group pull-right']/select[@name='per_page']"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "name" attribute instead of "class" attribute:

```
select_obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("per_page"))
select_obj.select_by_visible_text("100")
```

Hope it helps you!